# Больше одной модели в Django Admin Site

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Допустим, есть три модели:

```
class ModelA:
    pass

class ModelB:
    mA = OneToOneField(ModelA)

class ModelC:
    mB = ForeignKey(ModelB)
```

Можно каким-то образом в админке сделать так, что бы при выборе `ModelA` на одной странице с ней отображался и связанный с ней `ModelB` причем не в `Inline`-режиме, так как `ModelC` будет отображаться как `TabularInline` к `ModelB`?

То есть все три модели должны отображаться на одной странице. Сперва `ModelA`, ниже `ModelB`, а снизу таблица связанных `ModelC`.

Объединить `ModelA` и `ModelB` нельзя, так как сущности разные, отображающие совершенно разные объекты.